# Send forkjoin api with a delay in between each api

Tags: angular, angular6, ngrx-effects, fork-join

I currently working on an angular project where i have to use forkjoin to send multiple api in ngrx effect. There is a catch in this, i have to send the multiple api with a delay as if i send at once, they gets cancelled. My effect for the call looks something like this:

```
@Effect()
  timeslot$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(a.ItemActionTypes.GET_TIME_SLOTS)
    .map((action: a.GetTimeSlots) => action.payload)
    .switchMap(payload => {
      const serviceCol = payload.map(pl => this.service.getTimeSlots(pl));

       return Observable.forkJoin(serviceCol).pipe(
        mergeMap(result => {
          return [
            new a.GetTimeSlotsSuccess(
              ItemSearchAdaptor.allTimeSlotAdaptor(result)
            )];
        })
      ).catch((e: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        return Observable.of({});
      });
    });
```

Can anyone suggest any way i could use to have a delay in between API sending.

Comment: Can you write the this.service.getTimeSlots(pl) method here, so I can suggest you.

Comment: you can use the https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delay.html

Comment: @Sudhakar, that is the api endpoint creation method. Only creates api endpoints

Comment: Are those endpoints are observables? add a sample code.

Comment: @Sudhakar yes they are returned as observable.

Answer (score 0):

**getTimeSlots()** method should return the observables with [delay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delay.html) as shown give below. delay operator can be used to delay the request.

Be aware that if any of the inner observables supplied to forkJoin error you will lose the value of any other observables that would or have already completed if you do not catch the error correctly on the inner observable. If you are only concerned with all inner observables completing successfully you can catch the error on the outside.

```
getTimeSlots(pl){
            let observables = [];

            observables.push(http.doDelete(null, {})
                .pipe(delay(1000),
                    catchError(error => of(error))
            ))

            retur observables;
}
```